# UITextView/NSAttribute: Detect if word starts with a particular symbol

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I've been looking for a way to change the text in a `UITextView` when a word begins with either `"@"` or `"#"`. I found [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149122/how-to-change-color-of-text-stirngs-inside-uitextview-in-swift3) below on StackOverflow which works perfectly if you type `"Hello"` or `"World"`.

How can I adjust this code so it would detect if the word began with "@" or "#" followed by whichever number of characters follow it before a space, and apply the same styling?

The outcome would result in the color of the text within the `UITextView` changing if the user started the 'word' with an `"@"` or `"#"`. i.e.:

The quick brown **#fox** jumped over the **@lazydog**.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let defaultAttributes = mediaDescription.attributedText.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text, attributes: defaultAttributes)
    let inputLength = attrStr.string.count
    let searchString : NSArray = NSArray.init(objects: "hello", "world")
    for i in 0...searchString.count-1
    {
        let string : String = searchString.object(at: i) as! String
        let searchLength = string.count
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)

        while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            range = (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: string, options: [], range: range)
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
                attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont(name: "Karla-Regular", size: 16.0)!, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
                range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
                textView.attributedText = attrStr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You description is not clear enough. Please show some sample inputs and expected outputs for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [color hashtags in NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872815/color-hashtags-in-nsattributedstring) With a minor modification on the regex pattern, you should be able to detect either a @ or a # .

Comment: The added sentence is just a repetition, you have no need to repeat the same words already in the original post. And the input and output are still unclear... Do you mean your output still holds `#` or `@`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you keep `#` or `@` in the text, you can modify the answer in Larme's comment:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?:#|@)\\w+", options: [])

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText ?? NSAttributedString())
    let plainStr = attrStr.string
    attrStr.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSRange(0..<plainStr.utf16.count))

    let matches = regex.matches(in: plainStr, range: NSRange(0..<plainStr.utf16.count))

    for match in matches {
        let nsRange = match.range
        let matchStr = plainStr[Range(nsRange, in: plainStr)!]
        let color: UIColor
        if matchStr.hasPrefix("#") {
            color = .red
        } else {
            color = .blue
        }
        attrStr.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: color, range: nsRange)
    }

    textView.attributedText = attrStr
}
```

I just have changed the pattern, adapted to Swift 4.1, fixed some bugs, removed some redundant codes and added some code to change colors.

Comment: Works like a dream! Thank you!

Comment: Great, It works like charm but when am doing back space textview text color changes to the color of my hash tag.

Comment: Wow! nice solution works like charm! Thank you so much